# export entire pelican site as pdf?

Tags: pdf, pelican

Is there any easy way to export an entire Pelican site as pdf, sorted by category?

I tried dragging a sitemap html into calibre but this sucks in the navigation too, which I don't want.

It would be easy to extract only the  content from the html pages in the output folder with say python but then the pages are not sorted by category.

I could convert the .md files to pdf with pandoc but I have planturl images created from the markdown by a plugin so this wouldn't work either because the pdf wouldn't have the graphics.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Hacky homerolled solution: - I wrote extractDivs.py https://gist.github.com/stevepowell99/335ef06fe2b35b9317ed to go through the output folder and just extract the article div from each post, then put this in my makefile, after pelican runs:

```
python extractDivs.py
pandoc -s -S output/all.html -o output/book.html -c ../pelican-themes/monospace/static/css/main.css
wkhtmltopdf --footer-right [page] --footer-left [section] -R 30 -L 30 -T 30 -B 30 --outline toc ./output/book.html ./output/book.pdf
```

so pandoc takes the extracted divs and puts them into a single file with the same css as my cite, and then wkhtmltopdf converts to pdf.

Yuk.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is probably the [PDF plugin](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/pdf). The README only mentions reST, so I'm not sure if Markdown is supported, but if not it could probably be extended to do so.